# Angular app resolve, not controller, for async pre-loaded data

Tags: angularjs

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/lv9V723GTqk/jjlHle7QI04J) question, among many others, shows to use a controller-level `resolve` for async data that needs to be loaded before an application is started.

I have a lot of controllers, with all separately defined routes in each module... using `resolve` would be ridiculous to me *if they all depend on the data*. I also have directives which depend on the data (auto-complete search, etc).

Isn't there a better way to do: "load data (using an angular service) before each controller is shown"? I need the application to load, async fetch the data, and I use ng-show with some rootScope data that either shows loading or the controller template. I tried putting it in `app.run`, but couldn't get it to work properly...anything asynchronous in that block seems to wonk up the application.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. I'm not a huge fan of this solution, but it's the best I've been able to come up with so far.

First of all, you can have multiple `resolves` in each route, like so:

```js
resolve: {
  UserAccount: app.resolves('UserAccount'),
  Posts: app.resolves('Posts')
}
```

Since you can't inject application services into the config block, I created a big old object in another file that contains shortcuts to my services:

```js
app.resolves = (function(){
  // Resolves allow us to use `deferred`s to only
  // load our template after the data it requires
  // has been provided by the server.
  var resolve = {};

  resolve.UserAccount =
  ['Users', function (Users) {
     return Users.fetchActive();
  }];

  resolve.Posts =
  ['Posts', function(Posts) {
     return Posts.getAllPosts();
  }];

  // Public API
  // @param string name
  return function (name) {
    return resolve[name]
  };
})();
```

Comment: Is there not a way to specific an "app" resolve? If I have 15 different controllers, I only want to specify a "resolve" object once (app...resolve: mydata), not that same block 15 times.

Comment: Maybe you could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/N9eAz/

I haven't tested it beyond there not being any javascript errors. Your `app.resolveUsers()` function should return a promise, or an object with each member being a promise. As long as it's in your app config directly after your route declarations I would think it would do the trick.

Comment: Actually, try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/JJEHs/ This will preserve any existing resolves on a route. Just make sure you're declaring them in the object syntax like my route example.

Comment: I like that last one!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but since there's no accepted answer, nor a clean one, I am attempting to solve this too.

The lack of having a resolve state per app was bugging me for a while now, and this is the solution I finally came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielcatalin/cvyq0oys/

In short, I created an Angular Module Enhancer(decorator), which supports 2 more methods: **resolve()** and **ready()**. The AngularEnhancer snippet just needs to be loaded after the angular.js has loaded and before the implementation, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularEnhancer.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
```

This is how an implementation will look:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .ready(function() {
        alert('The app is ready to be used!');
    })
    .resolve(['$q', function ($q) {
        // The resolve can wait for a promise to be resolved
        var differed = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function() {
            differed.resolve();    
        }, 1000);

        return differed.promise;

        // Or a true value
        // return true;

        // Or even a truish value
        // return 'value';
    }])
    .ready(function() {
        // The order of where the ready() appear doesn't matter
        alert('This is just another alert to show that it can have as many as possible!');
    });
```

and the html:

```
<body>
    <div ng-if="!appReady" class="splash-screen">This is just the splash screen!</div>
    <div ng-if="appReady">Welcome to the app!</div>

    <script>
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Hope to see some comments from you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think that, since there's no obvious way to made app-level resolve configuration, the best thing you can do is actually modify the `$routeProvider` capabilities using a decorator. This way you can check if a `resolve` config is set on each application route and add/merge a special resolve promise that will either load async data or continue with the needed data, with the bonus of having a central point to test or modify when you need.

I'm struggling with this same issue right now. I'll try to make a generic/reusable code here and post my solution very soon on GitHub. I'll try to update this answer with a proper example here as well.